# Oracle - determining whether a table exists

Tags: oracle

How do you determine in oracle whether a table exists?
On a script file, I wanted to delete a table only if it exists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has an [`all_tables`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2105.htm) table, you could query that to see.

Maybe something like this:

```
declare
    v_tab_count number := 0;
begin
    select count(*)
    into v_tab_count
    from all_tables
    where table_name = 'MY_TABLE';

    if v_tab_count > 0 then
        execute immediate 'drop table my_table';
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('The table isn''t there! maybe you deleted it already?');
    end if;
exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line( sqlerrm);
end if;
/
```

I know I commented earlier on someone else's post that I didn't like using `execute immediate` for this, but I'd forgotten that it's the only way to perform a `drop table` from PL/SQL.

Comment: Great! User_Tables and All_tables (count can be 2 if 2 user have the same table) will it be better to use User_tables?

Comment: @kalls: You could maybe add some extra conditions to the query on all_tables or user_tables?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.dba-oracle.com/bk_check_table_exists.htm

There are various solutions given here. The simplest ones:

SQL> desc mytable

Or just try to drop and catch the exception:

```
begin 
execute immediate 'drop table TABLE1'; 
exception when others then null; 
end;
```

Comment: The DROP alternative is really awful, ignoring the obvious fact that wanting to know if a table exists is most often for wanting to have it!

Answer (score 1):

You can query USER_TABLES for TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME' :-)